# Display a loading component while waiting for the data

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I display a spinner while I'm waiting for the data to be displayed?

Is there a way to place a custom tag (from spinner component) in the HTML template where I'm waiting for the data?

My project is based on [Angular Drupal POC](https://github.com/vasike/ng-drupal-poc)

My list of articles component looks like this:

```
search() {
    this.sub = this.nodeService.getNodes({ q: this.q })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.nodes = this.filteredNodes = res;
          this.totalItems = this.nodes.length;
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ow do I display a spinner while I'm waiting for the data to be displayed?

Have a spinner component bound to some `loading` property on your controller e.g.

```
search() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.sub = this.nodeService.getNodes({ q: this.q })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.nodes = this.filteredNodes = res;
          this.totalItems = this.nodes.length;
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
search() {
  this.isNodeLoading = true;
  this.sub = this.nodeService.getNodes({ q: this.q })
   .subscribe(
     res => {
        this.isNodeLoading = false;
        this.nodes = this.filteredNodes = res;
        this.totalItems = this.nodes.length;
     }
  );
}
```

and define initially `isNodeLoading: boolean= false;`

then use in template like this:

```
<div class="loader-inner ball-clip-rotate" *ngIf="isNodeLoading">
       <div></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.